# How to create a Product Template

Tags: magento2, product, template

I'm trying to create a Configurable Product

The doc says to first create a Product Template:

> http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-templates.html?Highlight=product%20template

My version of 2.0.2 does not have a Product Template option. See screen shot:

> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bytqhoir_Tt5bHU5YWliWkFNZk0

How do I create product Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product Template was renamed to Product AttributeSet
[image]

Comment: Ah, then the v2.0 documentation is inaccurate and in error. Thanks @KAndy