# How to properly create product variations for configurable products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, products-management

I am getting a broad error when trying to save a product configuration:

> Some product variation fields are not valid.

See screenshot (click for full size):

[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bytqhoir_Tt5QlVac05QOHZ4UUk]

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the message is not very helpful and does not highlight which variation and which fields are invalid. I don't see what's wrong from the screenshot. The weight is missing but that *should* not be a problem. A possible reason could be an SKU that is already in the system.

You don't need to add all variations at once, try to add them one by one and see where it fails. Or if that still does not help, create them directly as simple products and then associate them to the configurable product. In the normal product form, the validation messages are more useful.

Comment: ok, i"ll try the stumble through adding the variations 1-by-1. As I mentioned, I made 6-7 different attempts to get them to take. Adding a Weight of zero (0) was one attempt, stripping out all hyphens and condensing the sku's was another. Nothing works.

Comment: The answer is that my "Simple Products" had "Default" set as the Attribute Set (formerly known as Product Template). Once I went through and changed each of them to the same Attribute Set as my Configurable Product, then Magento was happy and allowed me to save.

Answer (score 1):

The **Attribute set** for the "Simple Products" must match the **Attribute set** for the "Configurable Product" in order to connect them.

Comment: This is the answer. Stackexchange won't let me accept it for 2 more days. I probably won't be back to this post so anyway else that passes by -- please accept this as the answer or otherwise use it as the answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

apparently this is a bug. The workaround would be :
 1. create a configurable product.
 2. set up one configuration then try to save the product
 3. if you get the above error, go and create simple products for each of the options.
 4. Add each option using "Add Products Manually"

Answer (score 0):

i also faced same issue and finally i solved it 
issue is few of attribute are required filed that is why this error will come , 
to know which are the required field follow below steps

1. log in admin and and create new config product
2. soon after clicking save button internally one ajax call is happen , just try to see that response of that  ajax call it will be some thing like

   {"error":true,"message":"Some product variations fields are not valid.","attributes":{"variations-matrix-177-visibility":"The value of attribute \"visibility\" must be set","variations-matrix-177-description":"The value of attribute \"description\" must be set","variations-matrix-179-visibility":"The value of attribute \"visibility\" must be set","variations-matrix-179-description":"The value of attribute \"description\" must be set","variations-matrix-178-visibility":"The value of attribute \"**visibility**\" must be set","variations-matrix-178-description":"The value of attribute \"description\" must be set","variations-matrix-180-visibility":"The value of attribute \"visibility\" must be set","variations-matrix-180-**description**":"The value of attribute \"description\" must be set"}}

   after seeing the response you can identify the required fields  visibility and description Are the fields which causing the   **Some product variation fields are not valid.** error

or short way is go to product attribute grid and filter required to YES then you will get all required fields