# How to see simple products of configurable from admin panel

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

How can I see the Associated products of a configurable product? In magento 1 there is a tab on the bottom called Associated products. Where is it present in magento 2? Also, how can I create a configuration of a configurable product after I have created it?

Comment: I think they are "Configurations" now . look here: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html and here http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable-add-configurations.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a product in Magento with Multiple sizes](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107417/how-to-create-a-product-in-magento-with-multiple-sizes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here magento documentation:

- http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html
- http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable-add-configurations.html

Comment: Links have a habit of dying off (especially Magento documentation links) so you need to add the relevant content here in the body of your answer